# Ajax, jQuery, and JSONP

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

It seems like I can get JSON data from a different domain using jQuery's getJSON method (see: http://docs.jquery.com/Getjson). However, this works only for HTTP GET.

What if I needed to POST something and get the JSON response? How would I do that in jQuery/Ajax?

Comment: tvanfosson has been very helpful to me - and hopefully others - by commenting on my answer. I'd appreciate it if you'd consider giving him credit for the answer - which would give him my 50 point bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to POST requests to a remote server from the client using jQuery alone as of version 1.6.1 in all browsers.   If you attempt to make an XHttpRequest of any sort to a server in a different domain than the document, some browsers will simply fail to complete it. The JSONP requests to remote servers are handled by creating a script tag, the src for which is the API url with the query parameters added, including a callback method name.  Because scripts can be loaded from any domain, this works, but it limits you to GET requests. The remote host returns the body of the script which is the callback invoked on the resulting javascript object.  jQuery typically creates the callback function for you and from it calls the anonymous callback function you supply in the `getJSON` method parameters.

There are emerging standards, [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) and [UMP](http://www.w3.org/TR/UMP/) (see also the [comparison](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Comparison_of_CORS_and_UMP)), that some browsers support but not in standardized ways (read IE does it differently).  There are [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/cors) to provide partial support for those browsers that do support CORS.  No idea how well they work and they won't work unless the browser supports it.

Comment: The poster mentioned in a comment that he/she are responsible for building the API as well. If they implement the required protocol (which you can easily do if you already know how to build RESTful services) then this IS possible. See my other answer.

Comment: @Steve - my response is specific to jQuery, which doesn't support the rudimentary CORS implementations in those browsers which have it.  There's a barely supported plugin, but it doesn't seem to be under active development.  It's possible that this may change, but out of the box there's no way to do this with jQuery.

Comment: Actually, it does, as it uses XMLHttpRequest in the background... which will perform the OPTIONS preflight request automatically. I use this feature on a daily basis, and can attest that it works as described by the W3C spec in all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers aren't entirely true. This is possible if you have control over the server.

See: 
W3C - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Essentially, the client sends a "pre-flight" OPTIONS HTTP request, and, if the correct response is received from the server, it continues with it's regular operations. (There are plenty of examples online... Unless you need me to, I won't get into the details).

I understand this may not work in all scenarios (for example, I'm not sure if IE5/5.5 supports this or not... but I believe IE6 does)... but if you're working on an HTML5 app, and you have control over the server, this could be a possibility for you.

NOTE: Just an aside - Given the option I'd prefer JSONP, of course. Less to go wrong.

EDIT: There seems to be a lot of confusion here, so let me give an example of how one might do this using .NET / WCF (I think some of this came from an article somewhere, and other parts of it were developed in house... so if some of it came from somewhere else, I apologize in advance for not giving the due credit):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
    using System;
    using System.Web; 
    using System.Collections;

    public class CrossOriginModule : IHttpModule {
        public String ModuleName {
            get { return "CrossOriginModule"; } 
        }    

        public void Init(HttpApplication application) {
            application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
        }

        private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;
            CrossOriginHandler.SetAllowCrossSiteRequestOrigin(context);
        }

        public void Dispose() 
        {
        }
    }

   public class CrossOriginHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //Clear the response (just in case)
            ClearResponse(context);

            //Checking the method
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper())
            {
                //Cross-Origin preflight request
                case "OPTIONS":
                    //Set allowed method and headers
                    SetAllowCrossSiteRequestHeaders(context);
                    //Set allowed origin
                    //This happens for us with our module:
                    SetAllowCrossSiteRequestOrigin(context);
                    //End
                    context.Response.End();
                    break;

                default:
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Allow", "OPTIONS");
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    break;
            }

            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        protected void ClearResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.Clear();
        }

        protected void SetNoCacheHeaders(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            context.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
        #endregion

        public static void SetAllowCrossSiteRequestHeaders(HttpContext context)
        {
            string requestMethod = context.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"];

            context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");

            //We allow any custom headers
            string requestHeaders = context.Request.Headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestHeaders))
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", requestHeaders);
        }

        public static void SetAllowCrossSiteRequestOrigin(HttpContext context)
        {
            string origin = context.Request.Headers["Origin"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(origin))
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            else
                //This is necessary for Chrome/Safari actual request
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Web.config:

```
  ...
  <system.webServer>
     ...
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     ...
           <add name="CrossOriginModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="YOURNANMESPACEHERE.CrossOriginModule, ASSEMBLYNAME" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
           <add name="CrossOrigin" verb="OPTIONS" path="*" type="YOURNAMESPACEHERE.CrossOriginHandler, ASSEMBLYNAME" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: _"Given the option I'd prefer JSONP"_ - do you realize that JSONP exists only because of the same origin policy? If `XMLHttpRequest` could be used to make HTTP requests across domains, there would simply be no need for JSONP, which is a _workaround._

Comment: As per my response, XMLHttpRequest can be used for cross-domain requests. I do it all the time. But JSONP is more reliable in that it works in a much broader range of scenarios... which is why i'd prefer it. Workaround or not.

Comment: Seems like there's not much support for this in jQuery -- what exists is only partial and browser dependent (no Opera, support for example).  OP seemed to want a jQuery solution which isn't possible out of the box at present, at least across a full-range of browsers.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Actually, it does, as it uses XMLHttpRequest in the background... which will perform the OPTIONS preflight request automatically. I use this feature on a daily basis, and can attest that it works as described by the W3C spec in all major browsers. I can't vouch for Opera in particular, however... I'm only 100% sure abour IE 6+, Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: @Steve IE8+ uses XDocumentRequest, not XMLHttpRequest, to support CORS as I understand it.  I think you'd need to add some stuff to jQuery to support modern versions of IE.  Are you sure you haven't added the CORS plugin?

Comment: @tvanfosson: re: "I think you'd need to add some stuff to jQuery to support modern versions of IE. Are you sure you haven't added the CORS plugin?": 100% sure. Just using the jQuery ajax lib reference from google. Tested in IE 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: @Steve - I don't see any support for XDocumentRequest baked into jQuery 1.6.1 nor do I find anywhere they reference an OPTIONS verb.  I'm left scratching my head.  You want to add your client-side code to the post to show me how you're using it?

Comment: @tvanfosson: You're quite right... I'm looking into it now. You've got me curious. I know we're returning those P3P settings in the HTTP headers... do you know - does that change IE8+'s default behavior in this regard?

Comment: @tvanfosson: I've looked around and I believe I was wrong when I said it works in IE 8+ with jQuery "out-of-the-box". I guess my main issue with the other posts were they said "It can't be done"... which isn't really true - unless you're talking about Opera. I say in my post I'd prefer JSONP - exactly to avoid all of these complications - but it is possible. If you modify your answer I'll add a 50 point bounty to this question and up-vote your answer for teaching me something I didn't know before. For anyone reading, tvan meant "XDomainRequest" not "XDocumentRequest". http://bit.ly/eLtyd

Comment: @Steve - You're right on the request name (getting confused in my old age with LINQ for XML).

Comment: @Steve ...and +1 from me for encouraging me to dig into it more.  I see that there's more progress than I was aware of.  Eagerly awaiting a fully standardized, less painful way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. test.php

```
<?php   fire query
        $row = array();
        while($queryresults){
          $row['id'] = '$queryresults['idfield']';
          $row['name'] = '$queryresults['namefield']';
          $row['marks'] = '$queryresults['marksfield']';
         $output[] = $row;
         }
echo json_encode( $output ); //json array
?>
```

> 1. document ready

```
$.getJSON('test.php?query=query,function(data) {    
    $.each(enq_data, function(i,data){
          $('.anydiv').append('<div class="row">'+data.id+data.name+data.marks+'</div>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in short: JsonP is a cross-domain technique limited to GET request.